# Не работает calc(100% - 5.6rem) в Material ui

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, frontend, material-ui

Я пытался использовать makeStyles

```
result: {
  height: 'calc(100% - 5.6rem)'
}
```

Не работает.
Пробовал inline

```
sx={{ height: 'calc(100% - 5.6rem)' }}
```

Так же не работает
Но если использовать calc без 100%, то все работает

Comment: css в material-ui

Comment: calc не будет будет работать вне кавычек

Comment: Допускаю, что связано со стилями родителя

Comment: Если без 100% работает, то это означает, что значение 100% в том контексте, в котором вы его пытаетесь применять, посчитать невозможно, и material-ui здесь уже ни при чём